# NullpointerException when accesing 4d array with for-loop

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a code that goes through a 4d array writing the coordinates of each element into the element itself. The code is really simple i thought to myself and wrote this:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < s[j].length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < s[j][k].length; l++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < s[j][k][l].length; m++) {                       
                        s[j][k][l][m] = "("+String.valueOf(j)+","+String.valueOf(k)+","+String.valueOf(l)+","+String.valueOf(m)+")";
```

My problem is the array that I have to fill because its already filled with nulls and strings.

```
{ { { { null, "null", null }, { "full", null }, { "null" }, null }, null }, { { {} } }, { null, { { "full" } } }, {} };
```

So my programm start with s[0][0][0][0] goes up to s[0][0][3] and then it throws a NullpointerException. Its the moment where my programm comes to the 4th null of the array (excluding "null") and here I can't come up with a solution. In my opinion that null is not different from the other nulls but why does my programm stop here?

Comment: You are required to use a 4D array? Because I can't ever imagine choosing to do so.

Comment: @aliteralmind just go with it man. There are circumstances when they can be used, don't berate someone over it.

Comment: Yes, this array is given to me and I need to fill it with the coordinates.

Comment: Well, if it's a requirement, it's a requirement. When it's possible, I'd never choose a four dimensional array over a one dimensional array of objects that contain those sub-array values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the conditions of your loops you access the `length` property of the arrays. If the array value you access is `null` the `length`property can not be evaluated thus you get a NPE. 
The solution is, to check the array value for `null` and don't iterate over it's values as there aren't any anyways.
E.g. writing `s[j][k][l] != null && m < s[j][k][l].length` instead of only `m < s[j][k][l].length`

Comment: To avoid the null check in every iteration (in case the array value is not null) you could wrap the `for` loop in an `if` statement like 
`if (s[j][k][l] != null) { 
    for (int m = 0; m < s[j][k][l].length; m++) { 
    ...
`

Comment: I tried to check for null with if statements inside the foor-loop but to put it this way I didn't think of. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, when `s[j][k][l]` is `null`, trying to assign to `s[j][k][l][m]` results in an NPE.

This happens, for example, here:

```
{ { null, "null", null }, { "full", null }, { "null" }, null }
                                                        ^^^^
```

Comment: Adding a try-catch-statement for the npe solves this problem but it also ends the for-loops without allowing them to finish their job. I would need to add to the catch-statement that the for loops should continue their work from the point where they stopped but I can't write this in code, nor I'm able to tell if its even possible to do so :O                                                       If that null isnt different from the other null-values how can I check for this special case?